# How to set intellisense for Angular.Js and Javascript in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use Angular.js in Visual Studio Code. But it's not working. In visual studio 2013 I am able to get the IntelliSense, but not in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: it should 'just work' have a read of the 'Quick Fix' section of this article http://www.johnpapa.net/intellisense-witha-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 16):

In **Visual Studio Code**, just install following **npm** package and will get intellisense for **JavaScript** files.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/angular
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works, but how to get that to work for built-in angularjs services like $http, $q ?

Comment: Looks like there is no more support for services such as $http etc.
I just asked a very similar question and according to the answer it is not supported anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617075/angularjs-visual-studio-code-intellisense

Comment: running 'npm install --save-dev @types/angular' in project's root directory works for me.

Answer (score 12):

The answer provided here is no longer valid as `tsd` was deprecated. To install angular or any other `Typescript Definition`, please follow the next steps. Provided that you already have a `package.json` file and a `jsconfig.json` file:

1. First we will want to install typings globally: `npm install typings
   --global`;
2. Then, at root level on your directory run: `typings install dt~angular --global --save`.

You should now be able to have IntelliSense on your project.

ProTip! Include `typings/` on you `.gitignore` file before running the second command, to prevent git from watching changes to the newly generated folder for typings. You can also do that for `typings.json`, but I do not recommend it. Up to you.

I got the information from the github repository `readme` [file](https://github.com/typings/typings) and from [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/getting-angular-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code) post by Laurent Duveau.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get this warning message when installing `typings`: `Typings is deprecated in favor of NPM @types`. Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is given here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vscode/2015/05/21/getting-started-with-angular-and-visual-studio-code/

Take a look at the "IntelliSense for the Angular Module and Services" part. Be careful though, because there are some typos in the command lines.

Basically this is what you have to do:

**1. Install Node and npm on your computer (https://nodejs.org/en/)**

---

**2. Install TSD package using NPM**

Open your terminal or command line interface and type:

```
    npm install -g tsd
```

---

**3. Install the angular TypeScript file in your poject.**

Go to the root of your Visual Studio Code project, initiate tsd and add the angular TypeScript file:

```
cd /my/angular/project
tsd init
tsd query angular --action install --save
```

This should add a "tsd.json" file and a "typings" folder that contains an "angularjs" folder and a "tsd.d.ts" file.

---

**4. Add the TypeScript file reference**

Open the javascript file containing your AngularJS code and add the reference to the TypeScript file at the very beginning, so your file should look like that:

```
/// <reference path="path/to/typings/tsd.d.ts" />

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
// ...
```

(be sure that the line **is tripleslashed** and that the 'path' attribute corresponds to the "tsd.d.ts" file)

---

**5. Save and restart VSCode**

The autocompletion should work just fine in your js file.

**NOTE:** if you use several files containing AngularJS code, you should add the reference line at the beginning of all of them, but you should not need to restart VSCode again if you already did.

Sorry for the late answer, I hope it's clear and it will still help!

Comment: is there any alternative to add a link over every `js` file?

Comment: This appears to address Angular, not AnnularJs as the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 x64

```
npm init

sudo npm install -g typings

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

typings install dt~angular --save --global

touch jsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i am using node v6.10.2.
typings version 2.1.1

step to enable intelligence .

**install typings globally like:-**

```
npm install -g typings
```

**to check if tpyings is installed globally or not**

```
npm list -g
```

**once typings installed write:-**

```
typings install dt~angular --save
```

it will add some of files in your project to make angular globally.

**then install angular like:-**

```
npm install angular --save
```

once these steps done
**check it like:-**

```
 var app=angular.module('sample',[]);

    app.
```

once you type **app.** you will get the all members of app.

Answer (score 0):

Install "Angular Language Service" VSCode Extension!

**Features**

This extension provides a rich editing experience for Angular templates, both inline and external templates including:

- Completions lists
- AOT Diagnostic messages
- Quick info
- Go to definition