# How do I set up AngularJS intellisense on VS Code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I've been working on setting up Visual Studio Code specifically to work with a Angular 1.5 codebase that we have at work. Here's what I've done up to this point:

- Installed [TSD](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiyjLjg1dvNAhXDo5QKHZy_CcEQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.npmjs.com%2Fpackage%2Ftsd&usg=AFQjCNGAzyG2lgfrh5xiq3PhaekmY-JEjA&bvm=bv.126130881,d.dGo)
- Ran `tsd query -r -o -a install angular -s`
- Add a reference at the top of my file to tsd.d.ts like so:

```js
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('moduleName').controller('CtrlName',
    ['$scope', '$window',function ($scope, $window){

          
    }
})();
```

At this point, it looks like I have partial success; when I hover over the `angular` keyword I see type-specific information (i.e. `namespace angular`, `var angular: ng.IAngularStatic`) but none of the type information is coming through in the angular specific dependencies, i.e. when I hover over $window, it tells me it is of `any` type.

My questions:

1. What more do I have to do to get intellisense to work properly?
2. Is there a way around having to add the reference at the top of every single JS file I have in the codebase to be able to get intellisense working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206049/how-to-set-intellisense-for-angular-js-and-javascript-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity I saw that. It doesn't help unfortunately - it doesn't explain why intellisense works for angular but not for the angular services.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Intellisense/ and https://github.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense . Does these help you?

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity not directly - I'm looking to pull in intellisense for Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around, I found that this used to be supported in VS Code once upon a time but support was lost in the latest versions. Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8163