# AngularJS + Visual Studio Code Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created an AngularJS project and downloaded @types for angular. (npm install --save-dev "@types/angular") 
My problem is that in VSCode it looks like I don't get any type information for DI services like $scope, $http etc. For angular itself I get the list fine, but for $ services I don't.

For instance $http is reported as 'any'.

How can I get Intellisense and type information for those services too?

[image: no type information for built-in angularjs services]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done is correct, always VSCode did not support intellisence for injecting services such as $http.

You can't get support for those afaik. Since this has been stopped according to this **[issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8163)**.